# Checking if Bytes are 0x00

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, bit-manipulation

What is the most readable (and idiomatic) to write this method?

```
private bool BytesAreValid(byte[] bytes) {
    var t = (bytes[0] | bytes[1] | bytes[2]);
    return t != 0;
}
```

I need a function which tests the first three bytes of a file that it's not begin with `00 00 00`.

Haven't done much byte manipulation. The code above doesn't seem correct to me, since `t` is inferred of type `Int32`.

Comment: Would you mind to replace "best way" in the post with one of "most readable"/"most compact code"/"fastest code" or any other well defined "better" criteria? (Consider removing tags from title while you are at it).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> `t` is type-inferred to be an `Int32`

Yup, because the `|` operator (like most operators) isn't defined for `byte` - the bytes are promoted to `int` values. (See section 7.11.1 of the C# 4 spec for details.)

But given that you only want to compare it with 0, that's fine anyway.

Personally I'd just write it as:

```
return bytes[0] != 0 && bytes[1] != 0 && bytes[2] != 0;
```

Or even:

```
return (bytes[0] != 0) && (bytes[1] != 0) && (bytes[2] != 0);
```

Both of these seem clearer to me.

Comment: Knew there was a better way to clean that up. Thanks. +1 and answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
private bool BytesAreValid(byte[] bytes) {
    return !bytes.Take(3).SequenceEqual(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0 });
}
```

Comment: Or similar 'bytes.Take(3).Any(b => b!=0);'

Answer (score 2):

To anticipate variable array lengths and avoid null reference exceptions:

```
private bool BytesAreValid(byte[] bytes)
{
    if (bytes == null) return false;

    return !Array.Exists(bytes, x => x == 0);
}
```

Non-Linq version:

```
private bool BytesAreValid(byte[] bytes)
{
    if (bytes == null) return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (bytes[i] == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So that return `false` if any `0` exists?

Comment: Yes, it returns false (not valid) if the array contains a value that equals zero or if the array is null.